# can I make it parallelized?

Tags: python

it an answer for Euler project #4.

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is `9009 = 91 99`.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Answer:

```
906609
```

code is:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import product

def sym(lst):
    rst=[]
    for x,y in lst:
        tmp=x*y
        if rec(tmp):
            rst.append(tmp)
    return rst

def rec(num):
    num=str(num)
    if num == "".join(reversed(num)):    return True
    else:    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool=Pool(processes=8)
    lst=product(xrange(100,1000),repeat=2)
    rst=pool.map(sym,lst)
    #rst=sym(lst)
    print max(rst)
```

when I run this:

```
#    TypeError:'int' object is not iterable
```

but I can't understand it...isn't list iterable? or is there an error in my code?

Comment: A list is iterable, it's telling you that your not passing a list, it's an int.

Comment: A full trace-back would be helpful in pinpointing the exact location of the error, but the cause is as described in the error message and pointed out by @monkut

Comment: Just tested here, it is a strange error, it may have something to do with your attempt to print the max result before processing is finished... you can wrap a try/except around the iteration and try to debug a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with the function `sym`.

`sym` is being passed the first element of your product iterable.  (e.g. `lst = (100,100)`).  When you get to the `for` loop, you're iterating over `lst` and then trying to unpack it into two numbers -- equivalent to:

```
for x,y in (100,100):
    ...
```

Which fails for obvious reasons.

I think you probably want to get rid of the for loop all-together -- which was probably an artifact of your serial version.

```
def sym(lst):
    x,y=lst
    tmp=x*y
    if rec(tmp):
        return tmp
    else:
        return None  #max will ignore None values since None > x is always False.
```

The traceback was somewhat cryptic -- Apparently the traceback gets returned to the `Pool` which then gets re-raised ... But the way it is done makes it a little difficult to track.

Sometimes, when debugging these things it is helpful to replace `Pool.map()` with the regular version of `map`.  Then, any exceptions which get raised are raised on your main "thread" and the tracebacks can be a little easier to follow.

Comment: yup, just noticed here as well.  your passing [(100, 100), (100, 101),...]  to map, which will pull a single value from your input lst and pass it to the function, so sym((100, 100)) is passed.

Comment: +1 for `debugging these things it is helpful to replace Pool.map() with the regular version of map.`